# Android app not showing push notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

My Android app receive notification when foreground but doesn't show notification when background.

I debugged code and it goes through correctly without errors and logs everything but no notification remaining.

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if (Foreground.getInstance().isForeground()) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CallActivity.class);
            callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(callIntent);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Creating notification");
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "0")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                    .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.fcmNotificationBg))
                    .setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setContentText("Some text")
                    .setAutoCancel(true);


            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CallActivity.class);
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(CallActivity.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                            0,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    );
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

            Log.d(TAG, "Creating notificationManager");
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            if (notificationManager != null) {
                notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
                Log.d(TAG, "notify called");
            } else
                Log.d(TAG, "notificationManager is NULL");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check your receiver class getting fired?

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH how to do that?

Comment: Can you update how you register you receiver class? In manifest or in code? which version of api you are checking?

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH I declared `FirebaseInstanceIdService` in manifest with `<action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />`.  SdkVersion – 27

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast receiver has to be implemented

```
public class SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(context, MyFirebaseMessagingService.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

In manifest

```
<receiver
            android:name=".services.SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```